# How do I get past the bridge/dam in the chapter Surface Tension?

Tags: black-mesa, half-life

I really can't get past this. I'm starting this off with around 30hp. I'm quicksaved at the Dam. I'm out of revolver ammo, crossbow ammo and lazor ammo.

I had to throw it on easy mode (running normal usually) to get past some of this. I can pick off the guards from a distance using my pistol (since the machine gun is next to useless in all situations and the shotgun has limited range). Then I get to pick up some ammo and grab some health. I jump off the dam full hp, but then I have to deal with this water monster and the helicopter with no crossbow ammo and none of my guns shoot underwater. On top of that I have absolutely no idea where to go from there.

Anybody have suggestions on where to find crossbow ammo in this area or how else to deal with the water monster or the helicopter? Anything helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By this point you should already have received the Gluon (right click charges up, then release to "insta" kill).

What I did was, when you first see the soldiers going towards the dam, I waited until they actually passed the gates.  Next, I ran close to the entrance, where you can find two health kits. Then I fired a quick shot or two to trigger the aggros.

Then I ran back up the road to a fenced up power generator area, and camped a corner, equipping the shotgun.  As the soldiers came by, I would use the shotgun's secondary fire to finish each one quickly.

When you are at the entrance of the dam, you should see to the right a warehouse.  Enter inside, and you should find some Gluon Ammo and some other ammo packs. At this point, after you exit, a helicopter should come trying to murder you.  While normally you can't destroy it, using the Gluon can incapacitate it. Otherwise, you'll need to jump into the water (beware the monsters)

As for entering the water, if you got the Gluon, it should be a piece of cake.  Just charge and fire, or spam and fire.

After this, in the middle of the water, is a guard tower.  There should be a ladder, just go up, press the button, and you'll know what to do!

As Howdy_McGee [mentions below in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93311/how-do-i-get-past-the-bridge-dam-in-the-chapter-surface-tension/93331#comment127498_93331):

> Update on this - You can't fire it underwater. It just keeps clicking
>   like all the other guns. You can charge it above water and fire it
>   under water there but that's it. Either way got past it when I figured
>   out where to go and playing it on Easy.

Comment: As a side note, the helicopter is supposed to be unkillable, but you can kill it with the Gluon

Comment: So you can shoot the Gluon Gun underwater?

Comment: Indeed.  There is also an achievement for it.

Comment: Update on this - You can't fire it underwater. It just keeps clicking like all the other guns. You can charge it above water and fire it under water there but that's it. Either way got past it when I figured out where to go and playing it on Easy.

Comment: Note: You won’t have the Gluon gun at this point. It’s only available later on in Lambda Core (and Xen). The gun in question is called Tau or Gauss cannon.

Answer (score -1):

If you get lucky enough you can jump on the other side of the dam while trying to stick closely to the wall and land on the rocks without getting damaged. At least that's how I did it